# Show all of attribut and field during serialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, nullable

I have this XML File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?>
<body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <header><user>BOBBY</user></header>
    <in>
        <customer>0123456789</customer>
    </in>
    <out>
        <cmd>
            <productid></productid>
            <price></price>
            <date></date>
            <state></state>
            <type></type>
        </cmd>
        <cmd>
            <productid></productid>
            <price></price>
            <date></date>
            <state></state>
            <type></type>
        </cmd>
    </out>
    <state>
        <code></code>
        <desc></desc>
    </state>
</body>
```

With that file, i've generate this CSS Class :

```
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     Ce code a été généré par un outil.
//     Version du runtime :2.0.50727.5456
//
//     Les modifications apportées à ce fichier peuvent provoquer un comportement incorrect et seront perdues si
//     le code est régénéré.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
namespace DAL.XML.PDD.Test
{
    using System.Xml.Serialization;

    // 
    // This source code was auto-generated by xsd, Version=2.0.50727.3038.
    // 


    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class body
    {

        private object[] itemsField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("enter", typeof(bodyEnter), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public bodyEnter enter = new bodyEnter();

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("header", typeof(bodyHeader), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public bodyHeader header = new bodyHeader();

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("result", typeof(bodyResult), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public bodyResult result = new bodyResult();

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("state", typeof(bodyState), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public bodyState state = new bodyState();


        public object[] Items
        {
            get
            {
                return this.itemsField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.itemsField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class bodyEnter
    {

        private string customerField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string customer
        {
            get
            {
                return this.customerField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.customerField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class bodyHeader
    {

        private string userField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string user
        {
            get
            {
                return this.userField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.userField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class bodyResult
    {

        private bodyResultCmd[] cmdField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("cmd", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public bodyResultCmd[] cmd
        {
            get
            {
                return this.cmdField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.cmdField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class bodyResultCmd
    {

        private string productidField;

        private string priceField;

        private string dateField;

        private string stateField;

        private string typeField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string productid
        {
            get
            {
                return this.productidField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.productidField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string price
        {
            get
            {
                return this.priceField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.priceField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string date
        {
            get
            {
                return this.dateField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.dateField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string state
        {
            get
            {
                return this.stateField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.stateField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string type
        {
            get
            {
                return this.typeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.typeField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    public partial class bodyState
    {

        private string codeField;

        private string descField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string code
        {
            get
            {
                return this.codeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.codeField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string desc
        {
            get
            {
                return this.descField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.descField = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That's working great but when i serialise it, the empty attributs and elements or not presents :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <enter>
    <customer>0123456789</customer>
  </enter>
  <header>
    <user>Bobby</user>
  </header>
  <result />
  <state />
</body>
```

I've add a this code in my Cs Class :

```
    [XmlElement(IsNullable=true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("enter", typeof(bodyEnter), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public bodyEnter enter = new bodyEnter();
```

But i've this error :

```
    **InvalidOperationException**
```

Thank's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will:

1. Parse your XML from a string,
2. Deserialize the XML into .Net objects,
3. Output the customer name to the console (just to show that we have read a value from the XML),
4. Serialize the .NET objects back to XML, and
5. Output the serialized XML to the console. Alternatively, you may uncomment the TextWriter line and use the text writer in place of Console.Out, to write the XML to a file called "Test.xml".

Even without including the IsNullable attribute, the empty tags are still displayed.

Also, there is a disparity between your first XML sample, and the one that you were serializing - "in" and "out" from the first became "enter" and "result" in the second. I have kept the first element names, but feel free to change them in both the XML and code to match.

Good luck!

**Code**

```
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace DAL.XML.PDD.Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string sampleXML = 
            @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='us-ascii'?>
            <body xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>
                <header>
                    <user>BOBBY</user>
                </header>
                <in>
                    <customer>0123456789</customer>
                </in>
                <out>
                    <cmd>
                        <productid></productid>
                        <price></price>
                        <date></date>
                        <state></state>
                        <type></type>
                    </cmd>
                    <cmd>
                        <productid></productid>
                        <price></price>
                        <date></date>
                        <state></state>
                        <type></type>
                    </cmd>
                </out>
                <state>
                    <code></code>
                    <desc></desc>
                </state>
            </body>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(sampleXML);

            // Create our serializer of type Body, so that we can fill out members
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Body));

            // Deserialize the parsed XML into .Net objects
            Body body = (Body)serializer.Deserialize(doc.CreateReader());

            // Example that we have parsed correctly - output BOBBY
            Console.WriteLine(body.Header.User);

            // Use this to write the xml to a file 
            //TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter("Test.xml");

            // Serialize this object (back into XML) and write it to the console with empty tags
            serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, body);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    [XmlRoot("body")]
    public class Body
    {
        [XmlElement("header")]
        public Header Header { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("in")]
        public In In { get; set; }

        [XmlArray("out")]
        [XmlArrayItem("cmd")]
        public Cmd[] Cmd { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("state")]
        public State State { get; set; }
    }

    public class In
    {
        [XmlElement("customer")]
        public string Customer { get; set; }
    }

    public class Header
    {
        [XmlElement("user")]
        public string User { get; set; }
    }

    public class Cmd
    {
        [XmlElement("productid")]
        public string ProductId { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("price")]
        public string Price { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("date")]
        public string Date { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("state")]
        public string State { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }

    public class State
    {
        [XmlElement("code")]
        public string Code { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("desc")]
        public string Desc { get; set; }
    }   
}
```